# Hook ZwTerminateProcess in x64 Driver (Without SSDT)

Tags: 64-bit, hook, driver, sql-server-data-tools, kernel-mode

I found and read this question but I didn't found my answer [**SSDT hooking alternative in x64 systems**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597888/ssdt-hooking-alternative-in-x64-systems)

I want to protect my application against termination by other programs. In the 32Bit version of windows I used the `SSDT hooking` for hooking `ZwTerminateProcess` or `ZwOpenProcess`. I've to upgrade my program to using in 64Bit version of windows now.
And unfortunately in the 64bit windows we can't use `SSDT` hook ([**Because Patch Guard (KPP)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487353.aspx)), Notice that I don't want to Bypassing PG in this case and I've to use only kernel-mode hooking. For example, I don't want to my program begin terminated (Even )by the following code :

```
NTSTATUS drvTerminateProcess( ULONG ulProcessID )
{
    NTSTATUS          ntStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    HANDLE            hProcess;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
    CLIENT_ID         ClientId;

    DbgPrint( "drvTerminateProcess( %u )", ulProcessID );

    InitializeObjectAttributes( &ObjectAttributes, NULL, OBJ_INHERIT, NULL, NULL ); 

    ClientId.UniqueProcess = (HANDLE)ulProcessID;
    ClientId.UniqueThread  = NULL;

    __try
    {
        ntStatus = ZwOpenProcess( &hProcess, PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, &ObjectAttributes, &ClientId );
        if( NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus) )
        {
            ntStatus = ZwTerminateProcess( hProcess, 0 );
            if( !NT_SUCCESS(ntStatus) )
                DbgPrint( "ZwTerminateProcess failed with status : %08X\n", ntStatus );

            ZwClose( hProcess );
        }
        else
            DbgPrint( "ZwOpenProcess failed with status : %08X\n", ntStatus );
    }
    __except( EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER )
    {
        ntStatus = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
        DbgPrint( "Exception caught in drvTerminateProcess()" );
    }

    return ntStatus;
}
```

To do this work I used the following function (`NewZwOpenProcess`) and replace it with the original `ZwOpenProcess`  in SSDT but in x64 windows I don't know what should I do :( :

```
NTSTATUS NewZwOpenProcess(
        OUT PHANDLE ProcessHandle,
        IN ACCESS_MASK DesiredAccess,
        IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
        IN PCLIENT_ID ClientId OPTIONAL)
{
        HANDLE ProcessId;

    __try 
    {
            ProcessId = ClientId->UniqueProcess;
    }
    __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
    {
       return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }
   
   if (ProcessId == (HANDLE)11) //Check if the PID matches our protected process PID (My programm)
    {
     return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED; 
    }
  else 
    return OldZwOpenProcess(ProcessHandle, DesiredAccess,ObjectAttributes, ClientId);
}
```

Any idea ??

(Excuse me if my English is bad )

Comment: And that's why we like Patch Guard.

Comment: @HansPassant :), Yes we love PG, But I'm developing security software and it's important for me to protect my programs.

Comment: Microsoft developed PG so you don't need these kind of gawdawful hacks anymore.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes you're right, But PG only prevent rootkits and kernel mode malware, and isn't for user land defense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found my answer, I use kernel mode callbacks .

```
#include <ntddk.h>
#include <common.h>

// coded by Behrooz

VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{

    FreeProcFilter();
    DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"Unloaded\n");
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,  IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{

    NTSTATUS status = RegisterCallbackFunction();
  if(!NT_SUCCESS(status))
  {
     DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"Faild to RegisterCallbackFunction .status : 0x%X \n",status);
  }
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadRoutine;

    DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"Driver Loaded\n");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;

}
//
// PRE OPERATION
//
OB_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS ObjectPreCallback(
  IN  PVOID RegistrationContext,
  IN  POB_PRE_OPERATION_INFORMATION OperationInformation
)
{
    LPSTR ProcName;
    // OB_PRE_OPERATION_INFORMATION OpInfo;



UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistrationContext);


ProcName=GetProcessNameFromPid(PsGetProcessId((PEPROCESS)OperationInformation->Object));

if( !_stricmp(ProcName,"calc.exe") )
{
    if (OperationInformation->Operation == OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE)
     {
       if ((OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.OriginalDesiredAccess & PROCESS_TERMINATE) == PROCESS_TERMINATE)
         {
           OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess &= ~PROCESS_TERMINATE;
         }
       if ((OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.OriginalDesiredAccess & PROCESS_VM_OPERATION) == PROCESS_VM_OPERATION)
        {
          OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess &= ~PROCESS_VM_OPERATION;
        }
       if ((OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.OriginalDesiredAccess & ~PROCESS_VM_READ) == PROCESS_VM_READ)
        {
         OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess &= ~PROCESS_VM_READ;
        }
      if ((OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.OriginalDesiredAccess & PROCESS_VM_WRITE) == PROCESS_VM_WRITE)
        {
         OperationInformation->Parameters->CreateHandleInformation.DesiredAccess &= ~PROCESS_VM_WRITE;
        }
     }
}
    DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"ObjectPreCallback ----> Process Name [%s] \n", ProcName);
   return OB_PREOP_SUCCESS;
}
//
//POST OPERATION
//

VOID ObjectPostCallback(
  IN  PVOID RegistrationContext,
  IN  POB_POST_OPERATION_INFORMATION OperationInformation
)
{
   DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"PostProcCreateRoutine. \n");
}
//
// REGISTE CALLBACK FUNCTION
//

NTSTATUS RegisterCallbackFunction()
{
    NTSTATUS ntStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    UNICODE_STRING Altitude;
    USHORT filterVersion = ObGetFilterVersion();
    USHORT registrationCount = 1;
    OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION RegisterOperation;
    OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION RegisterCallBack;
    REG_CONTEXT RegistrationContext;
    memset(&RegisterOperation, 0, sizeof(OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION));
    memset(&RegisterCallBack, 0, sizeof(OB_CALLBACK_REGISTRATION));
    memset(&RegistrationContext, 0, sizeof(REG_CONTEXT));
    RegistrationContext.ulIndex = 1;
    RegistrationContext.Version = 120;
    if (filterVersion == OB_FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION) {
        DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"Filter Version is correct.\n");

        RegisterOperation.ObjectType = PsProcessType;
        RegisterOperation.Operations = OB_OPERATION_HANDLE_CREATE;
        RegisterOperation.PreOperation = ObjectPreCallback;
        RegisterOperation.PostOperation = ObjectPostCallback;
        RegisterCallBack.Version = OB_FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION;
        RegisterCallBack.OperationRegistrationCount = registrationCount;
        RtlInitUnicodeString(&Altitude, L"XXXXXXX");
        RegisterCallBack.Altitude = Altitude;
        RegisterCallBack.RegistrationContext = &RegistrationContext;
        RegisterCallBack.OperationRegistration = &RegisterOperation;
        DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"Register Callback Function Entry.\n");


        ntStatus = ObRegisterCallbacks(&RegisterCallBack, &_CallBacks_Handle);
        if (ntStatus == STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL,"Register Callback Function Successful.\n");
        }
        else {
            if (ntStatus == STATUS_FLT_INSTANCE_ALTITUDE_COLLISION) {
                DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"Status Filter Instance Altitude Collision.\n");
            }
            if (ntStatus == STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER) {
               DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"Status Invalid Parameter.\n");
            }
            if (ntStatus == STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED) {
                DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"The callback routines do not reside in a signed kernel binary image.\n");
            }
            if (ntStatus == STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES) {
               DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"Status Allocate Memory Failed.\n");
            }
              DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"Register Callback Function Failed with 0x%08x\n",ntStatus);
        }
    }
    else {
               DbgPrintEx( DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID,  DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL,"Filter Version is not supported.\n");
    }
    return ntStatus;
}
//
// FREE PROC FILTER
//

NTSTATUS FreeProcFilter()
{
    // if the callbacks are active - remove them
    if (NULL != _CallBacks_Handle)
    {
        ObUnRegisterCallbacks(_CallBacks_Handle);
        _CallBacks_Handle=NULL;
    }
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}


LPSTR GetProcessNameFromPid(HANDLE pid)
{
    PEPROCESS Process;
    if (PsLookupProcessByProcessId(pid, & Process) == STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER)
    {
        return "pid???";
    }
    return (LPSTR)PsGetProcessImageFileName(Process);

}
```

common.h

```
#include <ntddk.h>

// coded by Behrooz

//-----------------------------------------------
//  Defines
//-----------------------------------------------

//Process Security and Access Rights
#define PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD  (0x0002)
#define PROCESS_CREATE_PROCESS (0x0080)
#define PROCESS_TERMINATE      (0x0001)
#define PROCESS_VM_WRITE       (0x0020)
#define PROCESS_VM_READ        (0x0010)
#define PROCESS_VM_OPERATION   (0x0008)
#define PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME (0x0800)


#define MAXIMUM_FILENAME_LENGTH 256
//-----------------------------------------------
// callback
//-----------------------------------------------

PVOID _CallBacks_Handle = NULL;

typedef struct _OB_REG_CONTEXT {
    __in USHORT Version;
    __in UNICODE_STRING Altitude;
    __in USHORT ulIndex;
    OB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION *OperationRegistration;
} REG_CONTEXT, *PREG_CONTEXT;


//-----------------------------------------------
// PID2ProcName
//-----------------------------------------------
extern UCHAR *PsGetProcessImageFileName(IN PEPROCESS Process);

extern   NTSTATUS PsLookupProcessByProcessId(
     HANDLE ProcessId,
    PEPROCESS *Process
);
typedef PCHAR (*GET_PROCESS_IMAGE_NAME) (PEPROCESS Process);
GET_PROCESS_IMAGE_NAME gGetProcessImageFileName;

LPSTR GetProcessNameFromPid(HANDLE pid);



//-----------------------------------------------
//  Forward Declaration
//-----------------------------------------------
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, 
    IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath
    );

VOID UnloadDriver(
    IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject
    );

OB_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS ObjectPreCallback(
  IN  PVOID RegistrationContext,
  IN  POB_PRE_OPERATION_INFORMATION OperationInformation
  );

VOID ObjectPostCallback(
  IN  PVOID RegistrationContext,
  IN  POB_POST_OPERATION_INFORMATION OperationInformation
  );

NTSTATUS RegisterCallbackFunction() ;
NTSTATUS FreeProcFilter();
```

The result of my test:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, tell me, what version of WDK you are using?

Comment: @navossoc You're Welcome, WINDDK ver 7600.16385.1

Comment: I have tried this code but the `ObRegisterCallbacks` return `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` even though I have signed my driver. help me please,

Comment: @Behrooz, your solution also works in Windows 32 bits?

Comment: @Behrooz, can you share the .inf file you used?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for you code, and I test it on win10 x64 success.
BTW, I was found the ObRegisterCallbacks return STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED even though I have signed my driver.
So I asks many peoples, and then I find a solution for it.
Append this text in you "source" file:
LINKER_FLAGS=/integritycheck

then you can rebuild and resign your driver. It was found in bbs.pediy.com

Answer (score 2):

Someone can do "ObUnregisterCallbacks" and even register their own to prevent you from detecting it.

Comment: And your own code can verify if the callback is still present. This is what most decent AVs or ACs do, they attempt to register the callback again, and if the action succeeds it means the callback has been removed so punish!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like .inf file is not needed. just SC CREATE ServiceName type= kernel binPath= pathtoyourfile.